# CSS3 space outside drop shadow

Tags: css

I have the following CSS on a list of li items.

```
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius:10px; 
box-shadow: 8px 8px 4px #666;
-o-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-icab-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
```

I would like to have some spacing between the elements aswell, to make the drop shadow stop overlapping the next element.

The problem is the shadow and rounded corners has to be on the li, and can not just be moved to a div inside, for the spacing then to be put on the li itself.

The reason for this is, that I change background color on the li elements with ajax, and if I apply a background color to the li, and the shadow is on a child element, then the background color will be shown where the shadow is not, outside the box, hope this makes sense.

Comment: Use margin? Otherwise a http://jsfiddle.net/ would be nice

Comment: Could you just give a negative margin to one side of the box-shadow and then make the other slightly longer to "scoot" the box where you need it. You follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `height` and `margin` properties (set some values that are good for you) like this:

```
li {
    height: 35px;
    margin:0 15px 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px; 
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 4px #666;
    -o-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -icab-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. Oh, if you want to *fiddle* with it: http://jsfiddle.net/codenighter/FUUwG/ . I've added the `padding` property to put some space between the border and the text, and the margin on the left is set to 15px (but you can ignore that or changed it).